# VB.NET - Tab Control - Drag and Detach Tab

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, tabs

With the help of the code below (by LarsTech - [drag and detach tabpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043318/drag-and-detach-tabpages/35261436#35261436)
) I was able to detach a tabpage and place it into a new form. But when I close that form the dragged tabpage doesn't return to its original position. 
If anyone out there can help me program this, it'll be great!

```
 Private Sub TabControl1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.MouseMove  
    If (e.Button = MouseButtons.Left) Then 
         TabControl1.DoDragDrop(TabControl1.SelectedTab, DragDropEffects.Move)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_GiveFeedback(sender As Object, e As GiveFeedbackEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.GiveFeedback
    e.UseDefaultCursors = False
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_QueryContinueDrag(sender As Object, e As QueryContinueDragEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.QueryContinueDrag
    If Control.MouseButtons <> MouseButtons.Left Then
       e.Action = DragAction.Cancel
       Dim f As New Form
       f.Size = New Size(400, 300)
       f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
       f.Location = MousePosition
       Dim tc As New TabControl
       tc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
       tc.TabPages.Add(TabControl1.SelectedTab)
       f.Controls.Add(tc)
       f.Show()
       Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Else
       e.Action = DragAction.Continue
       Me.Cursor = Cursors.Help
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to do so?  If you expect that to happen then you have to write code to do it.  You already have code to move a `TabPage` so you can adapt that, but you'll have to also remember where it came from so that you can put it back there afterwards.

Comment: Sorry I guess I didn't make myself clear. I know that the code is not suppose to return the Tabpage to its original position. I am not able to produce the code which can do that task and that's what I need help with.

Comment: As I said, you already know how to move a `TabPage` from one place to another because you're already doing it.  You would have two options for moving it back.  Firstly, you could have the original form handle the `FormClosed` event of the second form and pull the `TabPage` back.  Secondly, you could have the second form keep a reference to the `TabControl` on the first form and push it back.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to produce the code which returns the tabpage to its original place when the form closes, however the page doesn't return to the original index position. Below is the updated code:

```
Public f As Form

Private Sub TabControl1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.MouseMove
    If (e.Button = MouseButtons.Left) Then
        TabControl1.DoDragDrop(TabControl1.SelectedTab, DragDropEffects.Move)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_GiveFeedback(sender As Object, e As GiveFeedbackEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.GiveFeedback
    e.UseDefaultCursors = False
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_QueryContinueDrag(sender As Object, e As QueryContinueDragEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.QueryContinueDrag
    f = New Form
    If Control.MouseButtons <> MouseButtons.Left Then
        e.Action = DragAction.Cancel
        AddHandler f.FormClosing, AddressOf ClosingDraggableWindow_EventHandler
        f.Size = New Size(400, 300)
        f.Name = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text
        f.TabIndex = TabControl1.SelectedTab.TabIndex
        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        f.Location = MousePosition
        Dim tc As New TabControl()
        tc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        tc.TabPages.Add(TabControl1.SelectedTab)
        f.Controls.Add(tc)
        f.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Sub ClosingDraggableWindow_EventHandler()
    Dim tbp As New TabPage()
    tbp.Text = f.Name
    Dim tbc As TabControl = f.Controls(0)
    Dim tbp2 As TabPage = tbc.TabPages(0)
    TabControl1.TabPages.Insert(f.TabIndex + 1, tbp2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing this sentence

```
f.TabIndex = TabControl1.SelectedTab.TabIndex
```

to

```
f.TabIndex = TabControl1.SelectedIndex
```

it works fine.

TabIndex represents the order into the form but not the index into the TabControl1.